# OAuth 2.0 with introspection .net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

I am looking for a sample application with OAuth 2.0 and introspection I find many links but no one giving specific documents or steps to implement OAuth with introspection.

Comment: Does this [link](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection) helpful?

Comment: i have already added this package but don't know how to use it where is JWT configuration how can i bind a token endpoint.